# Sum of adjacent cells based on first cell

Tags: google-sheets

Please I want to calculate the sum of adjacent cell based on the first cell

[image]

As you can see in the picture in the column C there is the sum of all the adjacent cells in column B of each transaction based on the number in column A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the setup in your post, delete everything from C:C. Then place the following formula in C1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,VLOOKUP(A:A,QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},A:A<>""),2,TRUE),B:B},"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1"),2,FALSE)))`

I encourage you (and others who may be interested) to use free columns in a test sheet to see what each of the following cumulative pieces does on its own:

1.) `=FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},A:A<>"")`

2.) `=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},A:A<>""),2,TRUE))`

3.) `=ArrayFormula({VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},A:A<>""),2,TRUE),B:B})`

4.) `=ArrayFormula(QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},A:A<>""),2,TRUE),B:B},"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1"))`

5.) `=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(A:A,QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},A:A<>""),2,TRUE),B:B},"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1"),2,FALSE))`

and finally the full formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,VLOOKUP(A:A,QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},A:A<>""),2,TRUE),B:B},"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1"),2,FALSE)))`

Comment: I have a little problem please, when the ID has a letter inside the formula doesn't work anymore

Comment: The problem is not clear from your description. Typically, if you have additional questions (especially after weeks have gone by), you should create a separate post. However, if you share a link to the sheet here in the comments, I will take a look.